# Create a windows service from windows application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows application built by c# and I need to run it every now and then, so I would like to create it as a windows service. How is it possible to create the windows service from the existing soluion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's easier for you to call it as a Scheduled Task, that way you won't need extra coding.

Comment: But is this a better solution or the windows service more efficient?

Comment: A Windows Service is a process which is running all the time, a scheduled task will only run the process once. So for simple things like yours it's more efficient in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SrvAny](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) tool to run your existing application as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this depends on how you coded your application :)  Generally, if I am writing a class that is "service-like" (e.g, it starts, stops, and can be paused), I will write it just like that.  I can instantiate this class anywhere I wish.

This makes it very easy when it comes time to turn it in to a real windows service as I simply create the windows service using Visual Studio, and drop my class in, mapping Start/Stop handlers to my calls.

I've found this approach over the years, in both C++ and C# to save a lot of ball-ache with services.  It does, for example, make it trivial to place the class in a console-application and test it without having to start and stop through the services interface.